# What is a RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox server name for outlook.com?

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

What is a `RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox` server name for outlook.com ?

'Logon' with local outlook is working.

I was try redemption with my outlook.com account with `RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox('user@outlook.com', server_name )`, and got MAPI_E_NETWORK_ERROR.

Internet is on. Firewall is off.

`server_name` I've got from outlook account settings - may be it's wrong?

How to get the actual exchange name for `outlook.com` ?

**UPD**

MS Outlook 2010 SP1 и 2013 (both same result)

Redemption v5.12

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem ? If yes, can you share it with me pls ?

Answer (score 0):

`LogonExchangeMailbox` creates a temporary profile that uses plain RPC connection. Exchange 2013 and 2016 do not support RPC connections anymore, only RPC-over-HTTP or MAPI-over-HTTP. You need to use `LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` for that.

Comment: `LogonHostedExchangeMailbox(''smtp-mail.outlook.com'', mail_box, password)` or `LogonHostedExchangeMailbox(''smtp.office365.com'', mail_box, password)` doesn't work. Is `SMTPAddress` arg mean something else?

Comment: You need to pass an SMTP address, not the address of an SMTP server. Pass something like "TheUser@domain.com".

Comment: I call `RDOSession1.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox( 'user@outlook.com', 'user@outlook.com', pass )`, and got `'DNS Server Reports Query Name error'`. Outlook 2010

Comment: You need to make sure you are using Redemption 5.12 under Outlook 2010 SP2, Outlook 2013 SP1, or Outlook 2016.

Comment: Sorry, update to Outlook2013 doesn't help. `RDOSession1.GetAutodiscoverXml` and `RDOSession1.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` raise a same DNS error

Comment: I sent the debug version of Redemption to your private email address.