# RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox doesn't try to login

Tags: outlook-redemption

I have a project that I have to migrate from Windows Server 2013 to Server 2016.
This project use `Redemption 4.2` to send the mail. But it works on 2013 but not in 2016

My server Exchange is 2010.

My code

```
Public RDOSession As Redemption.RDOSession
Set RDOSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Ecrire_Log "Avant RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox"
RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox colEmetteurTestComplet.Item(1), strServeurSMTP
Ecrire_Log "RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox :  loggedon " & RDOSession.LoggedOn

EnvoyerMessageExchangeRDO_err:
    Ecrire_Log "Fail to connect"
```

My log:

```
Avant RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox
Fail to connect - Err : Not logged on. Please log on first N° -2147418113 Source: Redemption.RDOSession.
```

It seems `RDOSession` can't be initialed correctly.

I found some post in SO about this problem with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42880768/what-is-a-rdosession-logonexchangemailbox-server-name-for-outlook-com) but they don't help me.

Comment: Please send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.