# Why am I receiving the 401 HTTP ERROR when calling GetSharedMailbox in Redemption?

Tags: exchange-server, mapi, outlook-redemption

I am using Redemption to access the shared mailboxes. The Logon method that I am using is **Session.**LogonExchangeMailbox****.

It seems to be working fine as long as I do not try to access the shared mailbox. Once I am trying to access shared mailbox, there is the following error:

*Redemption.RDOStores: Could not find the store DN
Could not retrieve autodiscover XML: GetAutodiscoverForEmailAddress: There are no autodiscover servers in the AD for this address
Error in WinHttpSendRequest(bcg.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml): ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT
Error in WinHttpSendRequest(bcgcloud.mail.onmicrosoft.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml): ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
Error in WinHttpSendRequest(autodiscover.bcgcloud.mail.onmicrosoft.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml): ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT
HTTP error 401 from https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml*

What I tried:

1. adding credentials with RDO.Credentials.add - does not change anything
2. LogonHostedExchangeMailbox - does not work in my case at all - I guess because of Basic Auth being disabled (and I cannot get OAuth token for modern auth)

Checking the server version with **Session.ExchangeMailboxServerVersion** has shown that we have 15.20.4995.8 - looks like we have Exchange 2019 where RPC-Over-HTTP is not supported anymore. Then the question would be how could **Session.LogonExchangeMailbox** work at all even with DefaultFolder? Why does it error out only in case, if I am trying to access sharedmailbox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redemption needs to retrieve autodiscover XML before it can open a shared mailbox. In most cases, autodiscover retrieval should still work with basic authentication, but opening the actual mailbox woudl still require OAuth token if basic auth is disabled. Is your code running in a COM addin or a standalone app?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As standalone app.

Comment: There is not much you can do in a standalone app. If running inside Outlook (COM addin) Redemption can at least intercept Outlook calls and extract OAuth tokens, but there is nothing it can do in a standalone app unless you give it an OAuth token.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your choice is only the `LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` method. Here is what the author of Redemption wrote:

> LogonExchangeMailbox creates a temporary profile that uses plain RPC connection. Exchange 2013 and 2016 do not support RPC connections anymore, only RPC-over-HTTP or MAPI-over-HTTP. You need to use LogonHostedExchangeMailbox for that.

See [What is a RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox server name for outlook.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42880768/what-is-a-rdosession-logonexchangemailbox-server-name-for-outlook-com) for more information.

In case of Exchange profiles/accounts I'd suggest using EWS instead. See [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information. Also you may consider using the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer - I tried using EWS with C#, but I cannot enable BasicAuth and there is following error popping up:

 X-AutoDiscovery-Error: LiveIdBasicAuth:BasicAuthBlocked

Comment: That is a subject for a separate question.